# php : show error on mysql query using concatenation

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, concatenation, php-5.3

I try to make new datatables and following this [tutorial](https://coderexample.com/datatable-demo-server-side-in-phpmysql-and-ajax/).
But, I got an error message :

```
"Error occuered during query execution: (<small>SELECT a.idrec,a.date, a.model, a.serial, a.item,a.symptom, a.remark 
    FROM second_sampling AS a
    WHERE 1=1 ORDER BY     LIMIT  ,   </small>): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT  ,' at line 3";
```

the syntax is :

```
$requestData= $_REQUEST;

$columns = array( 
// datatable column index  => database column name
        0 => 'idrec', 
        1 => 'date',
        2 => 'model',
        3 => 'serial',
        4 => 'item',
        5 => 'symptom',
        6 => 'remark'
        );
$sql = "SELECT a.idrec,a.date, a.model, a.serial, a.item,a.symptom, a.remark 
        FROM second_sampling AS a
        WHERE 1=1";
if( !empty($requestData['search']['value']) ) {   // if there is a search parameter, $requestData['search']['value'] contains search parameter
        $sql.=" AND ( a.date LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";    
        $sql.=" OR a.model LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
        $sql.=" OR a.serial LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
        $sql.=" OR a.item LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
        $sql.=" OR a.symptom LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
        $sql.=" OR a.remark LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' )";
}

$query=mysql_query($sql) or _doError(_ERROR30 . ' (<small>' . htmlspecialchars($sql) . '</small>): ' . mysql_error() );
$totalFiltered = mysql_num_rows($query);
$sql. =" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";
$query=mysql_query($sql) or _doError(_ERROR30 . ' (<small>' . htmlspecialchars($sql) . '</small>): ' . mysql_error() );
```

try to close the root cause and put:

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    echo "</pre>";
 ?>
```

then show :

```
{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":49,"recordsFiltered":49,"data":[]}
Array(    [sEcho] => 1    [iColumns] => 7    [sColumns] => ,,,,,,    [iDisplayStart] => 0    [iDisplayLength] => 10
```

Comment: Seems like `$requestData['length']` is not defined.

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they have been removed from PHP 7, your code will stop working when you upgrade to that version. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider i am using old php 5.3

Answer (score 1):

Your vars

```
$columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]
$requestData['start']
$requestData['length']
```

so the

```
 $sql. =" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".
 $requestData['order'][0]['dir'].
 "  LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";
```

produce wrong query clause

```
 ORDER BY     LIMIT  ,
```

Comment: before perform the query check if the var si my answer are empty  and the eventually assign default value for an use in the query

Answer (score 0):

In the output SQL there should be a column name between the `ORDER BY` and the `LIMIT`, and then two numbers separated by a comma after the `LIMIT`.

The fact this is not happening seems to indicate that the variable `$requestData` is empty, or at least not filled with the values you were expecting.

I would try:

```
var_dump($requestData);
```

to find out what is really in the variable `$requestData`.

Comment: OK! `$requestData` is a copy of `$_REQUEST`, but do you know what is in `$_REQUEST?`. It wil usually be filled when you are loading a page after submitting a form, or you are passing data with a query (so you see something like `?order=col` in the location bar of the browser?

Comment: What happens when you call the page with `?start=1&length=100` after the page name as the location?

Comment: sEcho:1
iColumns:7
sColumns:,,,,,,
iDisplayStart:0
iDisplayLength:10 this is the result

Comment: OK! Try  `"ajax":{ url :"employee-grid-data.php", type: "post", data: {start: 1, length: 100}} ` in the page that calls the script.

Comment: Or: `"ajax":{ url :"employee-grid-data.php?start=1&length=100", type: "post"}` should also work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115083/discussion-between-nunu-and-ben-hillier).

Answer (score 0):

Your Statement is invalid

```
WHERE 1=1 ORDER BY     LIMIT  ,
```

This part is the problem:

```
$sql. =" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";
```

The requestData `$columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]`,
`$requestData['order'][0]['dir']`,
`$requestData['start']`,
and `$requestData['length']` is empty.